# Keep Chrome Extension Pop-up from Resetting on Close

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular-material

I am pretty new to programming in general, but especially web development. I am making a small project that is essentially used to take notes. It is a Chrome extension and makes a pop-up after you click on the extension icon. I am using Angular and Material. Basically, the Pop-up has a textbox in it. Everything is working great except when I click out of the extension Pop-up, the app is reloaded and all the previous text is lost. Is there a way for me to have my extension only reset when the page is reset? I've dug through google's browser action documentation and I don't see anything that would allow me to do this.

This is my manifest.json file that chrome uses to load my extension:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "NoteMaker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "NoteMakerIcon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Note Maker"
      }
}
```

the Index.html file holds my app-root component, which has the textbox component.

I know I'm supposed to provide an example if possible, but hopefully, this is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `chrome.storage` (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local)

First, you'll need `storage` permission declared in the `manifest.json`:

```
   {
        "name": "NoteMaker",
        ...
        "permissions": [
          "storage",
          ...
        ],
        ...
   }
```

Afterward, you can use `chrome.storage.sync` (it will be synced to all browsers where the user is logged in) or `chrome.storage.local` (only current browser).

E.g. `chrome.storage.sync.set({note: 'text'}, () => console.log('Note saved'));`

`chrome.storage.sync.get(['note'], (value) => console.log('Note value - ' + value.note));`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I would also add that the popup doesn't have access to the current tab(https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs says the active tab will be undefined for a popup). So you need your popup to communicate with your [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), which has better access to the tabs API.

Comment: This is definitely what I need to do, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work properly. I'll open another thread about that elsewhere to keep this one clean. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome @LiamIhasz! Also can come handy - https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill. It provides a wrapper around WebExtensions API so you can use it as `Promises` and with `async/await`